# typeorm - Invalid object name on cascade insert

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm coding an app with nestjs where users can create draws and draw themselves. I try to implement cascade insert of data (like in doc [example](https://typeorm.io/#relations/cascade-options)) on Many to Many relation. Unfortunately, I got error:

> QueryFailedError: Error: Invalid object name 'dbo.draw_participants_participant'.

Here is db schema:
[image]

These are my domain classes:

```
@Entity({ schema: 'dbo' })
export class Participant {
  constructor(id?: number, name?: string, userId?: number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.userId = userId;
  }

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(4)
  @Column('varchar', { nullable: false, length: 50 })
  name: string;

  @Column('int')
  userId: number;

  @ManyToMany(()=> Draw, d => d.participants)
  draws:Draw[];
}


@Entity({ schema: 'dbo' })
export class Draw {
  constructor(id?: number, name?: string, secret?: string, finishDate?: Date, participants?: Participant[]) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.secret = secret;
    this.finishDate = finishDate;
    this.participants = participants;
  }


  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(4)
  @Column('varchar', { nullable: false, length: 50 })
  name: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @Column('varchar', { nullable: false, length: 50 })
  secret: string;

  @Column('smalldatetime', { nullable: false })
  finishDate: Date;

  @ManyToMany(() => Participant, p => p.draws, {cascade:  ['insert', 'update']})
  @JoinTable()
  public participants: Participant[];

}
```

It is saved in DrawService by using repository:

```
@Injectable()
export class DrawService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Draw)
    private readonly drawRepository: Repository<Draw>,
  ) {
  }

  createDraw(draw: Draw): Observable<Draw> {
    return from(this.drawRepository.save(draw));
  }}
```

and the enter data looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details to it like how you are calling to add these items? After a quick review, I just noticed that name in the `participant` is not nullable and is optional in the constructor. So are you making sure that you are setting its name?

Comment: @Yousefkhan i added more info

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the name of the junction table like the following.

```
@ManyToMany(() => Participant, p => p.draws, {cascade:  ['insert', 'update']})
@JoinTable({ name: "match" }) // as this is the name of your join table
public participants: Participant[];
```

See [more options](https://typeorm.io/#/relations/jointable-options) here if needed.

Comment: Something changed. I put `@JoinTable({name:"participant"})` but i got ` Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'name', table 'gift_draw_local.dbo.Participant'`. It's kinda wierd 'coz Participants have this property filled (like on the screenShot).

Comment: @Xalion You have to name the join table which is `match` in your above schema